# Deeplearning: Error when trying to add values to mask array

Tags: java, arrays, machine-learning, deep-learning

In deep learning, padding and masking are required when we have feature with different length. I am developing a sentiment analysis program which uses RNN algorithm. 
In my, program I am trying to add values to mask array I created. But it gives the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Indexes, shape, and stride must be the same length
    at org.nd4j.linalg.api.shape.Shape.getOffset(Shape.java:480)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.putScalar(BaseNDArray.java:1071)
    at MovieReviewClassifierModel.predict(MovieReviewClassifierModel.java:80)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel$$anonfun$1.apply(Predictor.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel$$anonfun$1.apply(Predictor.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUDF.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUDF.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:964)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificMutableProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(basicOperators.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(basicOperators.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am trying to add values to mask array by using following for loop.  Can you explain me the reasons for the error and how I can solve it.

```
int lengthOfFeatureArray=featureArray.length;
        INDArray arr=Nd4j.create(featureArray);
        INDArray featureMaskArray=Nd4j.zeros(maxLength);
        int[] temp = new int[1];
        for(int i=0;i<lengthOfFeatureArray;i++){
            temp[0]=i;
            featureMaskArray.putScalar(temp,1.0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `featureMaskArray.rank()`. It's most likely `2`, therefore

```
int[] temp = new int[] { 1, 1 }
featureMaskArray.putScalar(temp, 1.0);
```

might work

but

```
int[] temp = new int[] { 1 }
featureMaskArray.putScalar(temp, 1.0);
```

won't.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.